# install zabbix_sender in centos

Tags: yum, zabbix

I installed zabbix-sender but when execute zabbix-sender i get `command not found`.

```
[root@db1 zabbix]# yum info zabbix-sender
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
Name        : zabbix-sender
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 3.4.6
Release     : 1.el7
Size        : 1.0 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : _ftp
Summary     : Zabbix Sender
URL         : http://www.zabbix.com/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : Zabbix sender command line utility
```

when i use thi command

```
[root@db2 zabbix]# zabbix_sender -z zabbix -s db2 -k mysql[Binlog_cache_disk_use] -o 2000 -vv      
-bash: zabbix_sender: command not found
```

Why does this happen?

```
[root@db1 zabbix]# !r
rpm -lq zabbix-sender
/usr/bin/zabbix_sender
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/zabbix-sender-3.4.6/README
/usr/share/man/man1/zabbix_sender.1.gz


[root@db1 zabbix]# zabbix-sender -z zabbix -s db1  -k mysql[Uptime] -o 1540 -vv
-bash: zabbix-sender: command not found
[root@db1 zabbix]#
```

**checked again**

I understand why does this happen! I remove Zabbix-sender and install again. when using `Zabbix-sender -z Zabbix -s db1  -k mysql[Uptime] -o 1540 -vv` there is no problem and working but after execute `prel MySQL-check.pl root password` then `Zabbix-sender` it seems to be removed. Does anyone know why? I using this template [link](https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/template-mysql-800-items)

Comment: Your first snippet shows `yum info` used on `db1`, but the command in the second snippet is from `db2`. Sure you installed it on the server you intended to?

Comment: There is no difference. It is installed on both servers (`db1 - db2 `)

Comment: In your latest edits, you have shown that `zabbix_sender` exists, but then you try to use `zabbix-sender`. And later in the edit you mention `Zabbix-sender`. Please check at least 5 times your usage of dashes versus underscores, and the usage of uppercase/lowecase letters. Your edit also reveals that you are using a Perl script - check that the hardcoded sender name in it matches what you have installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

List files provided by rpm package:

```
$ rpm -ql zabbix-sender
/usr/bin/zabbix_sender
...
```

Try `/usr/bin/zabbix_sender` - do you have correct PATH setting (is `/usr/bin/` included there)?